# Bash script in crontab is not working

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

Contents of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

rm list0.txt list1.txt list2.txt list3.txt print0.txt print1.txt print2.txt print3.txt

sleep 5

./checkip-1.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
sleep 5

./checkip-2.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
sleep 5

./checkip-3.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
sleep 5

./checkip-4.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
sleep 5
```

The scripts within the main scripts are working fine when I run them individually but not when I am calling them from the main script. I trying to run this using this crontab entry

```
cd /var/www/html/dashboard/scan/ && autoscan.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script resides in `/var/www/html/dashboard/scan/` and the directory is not in your `PATH`, so you can't execute the script by simply doing `autoscan.sh`, which is searching your `PATH` for `autoscan.sh`.

You need to mention that the script is in the current directory:

```
cd /var/www/html/dashboard/scan/ && ./autoscan.sh
```

Or simply:

```
/var/www/html/dashboard/scan/autoscan.sh
```

Both assumes the script is executable by the user running it.

Unless you modify the `autoscan.sh` script, the last one won't work for you as you are running other scripts `./checkip-{1..4}.sh` using relative paths from `autoscan.sh`, so a `cd` into `/var/www/html/dashboard/scan/` is needed.

Comment: Thanks. The first option worked. I tried the second option it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @bran Check my edits..explained why the last one didn't work..